# ClientSide Migrations using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm writing a WPF application that uses EF5 as an ORM.
The application is in use on a different machine than the development machine (installed using ClickOnce).

I've created a migration in order to add a column to a table, and ran it on the development machine. How do I run the same migration on the client without loosing information?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to trigger migrations manually. Instead, if the dbcontext's initializer is set to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, the initializer takes care of migrating the database upon first database operation.

It is just as easy as running your application at the client side, assuming you don't do anyhting unexpected.